# How to LINK a Silverlight library to the files of a normal Class Library

Tags: silverlight

I have come across a Silverlight project that needed to make use of a normal Classlibrary to do certain functions. Since you can't reference a Classlibrary directly, the project linked Silverlight library to the files.

Wondered how this could be done, you can see in the screenshot below to what I am refering to.

[alt text http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/9840/referenceshortcut.jpg](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/9840/referenceshortcut.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to "add an existing item" to you silverlight library. Instead of simply clicking "add", click on the arrow on the side of the add button and choose "add as link". 
That will create a "shortcut" from the original file to your silverlight library.

Obviously you need to make sure your class does not make use of anything not in the silverlight BCL.